# Get Class from string -- Call function by string name

Tags: mixins, d, dmd

OK, what I'm trying to do is fairy complicated, but I'll try to explain.

Let's say we want (at compile-time) all `derivedMembers` of class `someClass`. Then we'd simply do :

```
const string[] methods = [__traits(derivedMembers,someClass)];
```

Now, how could we get `someClass` from `"someClass"`? (yep, its string representation).

---

Let me explain a bit more what I'm trying to do :

I want to create an "intermediate" function which takes a `function` name as an argument (along with a params array) and calls the appropriate function from a list of available static methods in a specific (predefined) set of classes. Like `execute("someFunc",["one","two","three"]);`.

**Here's the full (test) code :**

```
class Math {
    static string noArgs(string[] s) { writeln(s); return ""; }
    static string withOneArg(string[] s) { writeln(s); return ""; }
    static string withTwoArgs(string[] s) { writeln(s); return ""; }
}

string cases()
{
    string ret = "";

    const string[] methods = [__traits(derivedMembers,Math)];

    foreach (string s; methods)
    {
        ret ~= "case \"" ~ s ~ "\": return Math."~s~"(params);";
    }

    return ret;
}

string execute(string what, string[] params)
{
    switch (what)
    {
        mixin(cases());
        default: break;
    }
    return "";
}
```

**The trouble with the above code** is that it only looks for methods in `Math`. How could I change it, in an elegant D-friendly way, so that it'll go through an array of classes like `[Math,String,SomethingElse]` -- it doesn't have to be variable (we need it at compile-time anyway)?

---

**UPDATE:**

Tried something along the lines of :

```
const string[] methods = [__traits(derivedMembers,mixin("Math")];
```

but it complains that `Cannot interpret Math at compile time`.

---

**UPDATE 2:**

Also, tried using `Object.factory("Math")` but it's still not working. (Perhaps I'm just creating an instance of the `Math` class?)

Comment: Did you try with fully qualified name, like `Object.factory("com.example.kameleon.Math");` ?

Comment: @DejanLekic Seems like I resolved that part by using `mixin(className)` (which finally worked). However it's still not ok. Have a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23078009/use-a-loop-at-compile-time

Comment: Object.factory just creates an instance of it that you can later cast back or use through an interface. It isn't useful for compile time reflection though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me rewrite this to show you some cool tricks:

```
import std.stdio;

class Math {
    static string noArgs(string[] s) { writeln(s); return ""; }
    static string withOneArg(string[] s) { writeln(s); return ""; }
    static string withTwoArgs(string[] s) { writeln(s); return ""; }
}

class String {
    static string oneArg(string[] s) { return null; }
}

string execute(string what, string[] params) {
    import std.string;
    auto parts = what.split(".");
    auto className = parts[0];
    auto methodName = parts[1];

    import std.typetuple;
    switch(className) {
        default: assert(0, "unknown class");
        foreach(possibleClass; TypeTuple!(Math, String)) {
            case possibleClass.stringof:
                switch(methodName) {
                    default: assert(0, "unknown method");
                    foreach(memberName; __traits(derivedMembers, possibleClass)) {
                        case memberName:
                            return __traits(getMember, possibleClass, memberName)(params);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            break;
        }
    }
    assert(0);
}

void main() {
    execute("Math.withOneArg", ["cool"]);
    execute("String.oneArg", ["cool"]);
}
```

Notice that there are no `mixin` expressions used at all. Instead of getting an instance of the class from a string, I just made a `TypeTuple` of all the classes I wanted to use. This is preferable to `mixin` because then it is less likely to find name classes when used in different scopes; if `possibleClasses` were a compile-time parameter to `execute` from a different module, the list of classes would still work, whereas the list of strings would see undefined identifier errors because the library module doesn't import your user module.

Another `mixin` I removed was the one to generate the cases. This looks insane, but is allowed in D: if you have a compile-time `foreach` (that is, a `foreach` over a built-in tuple of some sort, e.g. `TypeTuple`, template argument lists, the results of `__traits`...) you can actually put `case` statements inside them!

So, all you have to do is write a regular `switch` statement on the run time variable you want to compare against, put the `foreach` inside it looping over the compile-time stuff you're searching for, `case that_loop_var:` and boom, you're in business.

Similarly, I used `__traits(getMember)` rather than a `mixin` string to call the method. This solution will help avoid name clashes and IMO is cleaner code. It can also potentially handle overloads, if wanted (with `__traits(getOverloads)` instead of `__traits(getMember)`, you can loop over each one then and match the parameter types).

Finally, nesting `switch`es inside other `case` statements is allowed. If you need to break out of an outer loop or `switch` and don't want ambiguity, you can label loops and switches and use `break label_name_here;` to specify which one you want to break from. Ditto for `continue` with nested loops.

BTW you could also automatically generate the wrapper functions that convert `string[]` to other types of arguments if you dove into the `std.traits` stuff. I wish my book was out already, I wrote about this at some length in there and don't feel like writing it all right now but if you look at `std.traits.ParameterTypeTuple` and `ReturnType` in the same module that will get you started if you wanna try it.