# Using a foreach loop -- variable cannot be read

Tags: mixins, d, dmd

Should be rather simple but it's not.

**Here's my code :**

```
string cases()
{
    string ret = "";
    string[] methods;

    methods = [__traits(derivedMembers,mixin("Math"))];
    foreach (string s; methods) ret ~= "case \"" ~ s ~ "\": return Math."~s~"(params);";

    methods = [__traits(derivedMembers,mixin("OtherClass"))];
    foreach (string s; methods) ret ~= "case \"" ~ s ~ "\": return OtherClass."~s~"(params);";

    return ret;
}

string execute(string what, string[] params)
{
    switch (what)
    {
        mixin(cases());
        default: break;
    }
    return "";
}
```

**What I want to do :**

```
const string[] arrayWithClassNames = ["Math","SomeClass"];
foreach (string s; arrayWithClassNames)
{
     methods = ...
     foreach ...
}
```

Rather simple huh? The thing is it complains that :

```
variable 's' cannot be read at compile time.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create a compile-time loop, you need to iterate over a tuple. Try this:

```
alias classNames = TypeTuple!("Math","SomeClass");
foreach (string s; classNames)
{
    ...
}
```